# Fortran standard and intrinsic procedure standard

Tags: fortran

In the documentation of the GNU Fortran compiler, for a specific intrinsic function, there is a *standard*. For example, `CPU_TIME` is an intrinsic procedure for which it is indicated that the standard is *Fortran 95 and later*. My question is about the meaning of this.

I understand the *Fortran standard* to be like a set of rules to follow for your code to be defined as standard-compliant (to Fortran 77,90,95,2003 or 2008). Does this mean that `CPU_TIME` can only be used with Fortran 95+? Actually, I already know the answer, I can use `CPU_TIME` within a Fortran 77 file with the .f extension without the compiler to complain, compiling with a Gfortran version > 5. Is that because the compiler is able to treat any standard encountered in a code? I am aware of the `-std` flag but how can I be sure that for instance a Fortran 77 code uses only intrinsic procedures for Fortran 77?

Comment: One thing I think you're confused about is the meaning of .f vs .f90 files. The file extension refers *only* to the formatting of the source code - free form or fixed form. Typing gfortran main.f doesn't mean it's using a F77 compiler.

Comment: @Ross : I am aware of free form/fixed form and the extension of the file  but I thought that typing `gfortran main.f` compiles a Fortran 77 code. I have trouble understanding the difference of what kind of Fortran (77,90 etc..) the compiler actually compiles and the relation with the standard.

Comment: If you need to be compatible with an old legacy compiler the most reliable check would be to verify with that compiler. Otherwise I wonder why you care about maintaining compliance with some old standard.

Comment: Ok, let's forget F77. Imagine I want to code strictly in Fortran 90. If I use `CPU_TIME` that is Fortran 95 standard according to the documentation, 1) isn't there a problem ? 2) Why can I use this procedure in a Fortran 90 oriented code ?

Comment: No, gfortran compile `.f` files as Fortran 2008 by default. And `.f90` also as Fortran 2008. The source form differs, but the standard in use is something else.

Comment: Ad 1) Gfortran writes Fortran 95 for anything from Fortran 95 and older.   For good reasons. Forget Fortran 90, it is not worth. Nobody uses it. Fortran 95 has superseded it completely. Fortran 90 had several drawbacks and serious problems which were fixed by Fortran 95. Forget Fortran 90. Gfortran also does not consider it. Ad 2) I don't know if it was introduced in 90 or 95 and I don't care.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, you can not distinguish standard below f95 with gnu compilers. From f95 and above, you can use the option -std to force the compiler to consider features of standard above as errors.

Long answer:

The [documentation of gnu compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Fortran-Dialect-Options.html) says this:

> -std=std
>       Specify the standard to which the program is expected to conform, which may be one of ‘f95’, ‘f2003’, ‘f2008’, ‘gnu’, or ‘legacy’. The
>   default value for std is ‘gnu’, which specifies a superset of the
>   Fortran 95 standard that includes all of the extensions supported by
>   GNU Fortran, although warnings will be given for obsolete extensions
>   not recommended for use in new code. The ‘legacy’ value is equivalent
>   but without the warnings for obsolete extensions, and may be useful
>   for old non-standard programs. The ‘f95’, ‘f2003’ and ‘f2008’ values
>   specify strict conformance to the Fortran 95, Fortran 2003 and Fortran
>   2008 standards, respectively; errors are given for all extensions
>   beyond the relevant language standard, and warnings are given for the
>   Fortran 77 features that are permitted but obsolescent in later
>   standards. ‘-std=f2008ts’ allows the Fortran 2008 standard including
>   the additions of the Technical Specification (TS) 29113 on Further
>   Interoperability of Fortran with C and TS 18508 on Additional Parallel
>   Features in Fortran.

```
- `-std=f95` will consider features above f95 as errors
- `-std=f2003` will consider features above f2003 as errors
- `-std=f2008` will consider features above f2008 as errors
- etc.
```

You might want to check with other compilers.

Easy verification:, compile the following program (courtesy of [Fortran wiki](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Object-oriented+programming)) with and without the option `-std=f95` and see what happens.

```
module class_Circle
    implicit none
    private
    real :: pi = 3.1415926535897931d0 ! Class-wide private constant

    type, public :: Circle
        real :: radius
    contains
        procedure :: area => circle_area
        procedure :: print => circle_print
    end type Circle
contains
    function circle_area(this) result(area)
        class(Circle), intent(in) :: this
        real :: area
        area = pi * this%radius**2
    end function circle_area

    subroutine circle_print(this)
        class(Circle), intent(in) :: this
        real :: area
        area = this%area()  ! Call the type-bound function
        print *, 'Circle: r = ', this%radius, ' area = ', area
    end subroutine circle_print
end module class_Circle


program circle_test
    use class_Circle
    implicit none

    type(Circle) :: c     ! Declare a variable of type Circle.
    c = Circle(1.5)       ! Use the implicit constructor, radius = 1.5.
    call c%print          ! Call the type-bound subroutine
end program circle_test
```